# Editing Signature Request email in resource file

Tags: docusignapi

I opened a ticket with DocuSign enterprise support and was instructed to post my issue to StackOverflow.

We are working on a new feature for a client in our demo account and would like to know how to override the content of the Signature Request email that is sent to a signer recipient when an envelope is created from a template. See the attached screenshot—we would like to change the name and email address that appear in the body of the email. Currently, it shows the main account holder’s information. I have looked through our Email resource XML and do not see an element that pertains to this email.

[image]

According to the Resource File guide, it seems like I might be looking for a `<data name=”DigitalSignaturesPending_HtmlBody”>` element. However, I do not see one in the resource file. I see elements for editing *other* emails that go to recipients, but not this email. Therefore, I cannot remove the desired fields. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to hide the sender's icon, name and email, you can do so in the *Signing* Resource File: Change `DocuSign_HideIntroductionSenderProfileImage = True` and `DocuSig
n_HideIntroductionSender = True`

If you want to change what appears in that block, check the *Email* Resource File. Look for lines that start with `[[Conditional:ShowIntroductionSender]]` and contain `[[Data:SenderName]]` and `[[Data:SenderEmail]]` and edit those accordingly. Note that you can only hard-code a name and email so that all notifications sent with that Brand will show the same data.
You will probably need to make several changes, as there are many notification types.

If you want to change who *owns the envelope*, consider setting up an [Envelope Transfer Rule](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custody-transfer) that fires Prior to First Send. You can have envelopes sent from your account transfer to a generic/faceless user, so all notifications will have that profile on them. Note that you may want to set up Envelope Sharing so that sending users can still view envelopes they've sent.